# Apache Drill: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Hash aggregate does not support schema change

Tags: sql, hdfs, parquet, apache-drill

Trying to run this query, brings the error  Hash aggregate does not support schema change

```
SELECT 
CAST (reporting_date as DATE) AS Datum,
Max(calc) AS max_calc
from TABLE
group by reporting_date
```

have any one faced similar issue .?

Answer (score 1):

When you use GROUP BY the columns in your SELECT that aren't aggregated need to match the columns in your GROUP BY exactly.

You have "CAST (reporting_date as DATE)" in your SELECT but "reporting_date" in your GROUP BY